# JQuery shake effect on error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply a shake effect to my login page when a user enters incorrect information. At the minute, if a user submits incorrect details, the page is refreshed a PHP notification is printed and the notification div is made visible via JS. I'm trying to use the notification becoming visible as recognition that the information is incorrect and toggle the shake effect.

HTML

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <p>
            Sign into <i>Agito</i> by using the credentials you were sent via email. If you haven't signed up yet, click the link below. 
        </p>

        <div class="pre-user">
            <img src="../resources/img/user.png">
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
        <div class="pre-pass">
            <img src="../resources/img/password.png">
        </div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        <a href="#">Haven't signed up yet?</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

with the following being printed when the page reloads

```
<div class='notification'>Sign in unsuccessful. Try again?</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.notification').hide();
    $('.notification').slideDown();
    if ($('.notification').is(':visible')) {
        $('.form-container').effect( "shake" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the jQuery UI library?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If the notification div doesn't exist initially on your page, you could also tidy up things with your jQuery.  In your CSS or PHP echo of the div, you can specify display:none; for the notification div and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".notification").length) {
        $(".notification").slideDown("fast",function() {
            $(".form-container").effect("shake");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function shakeElement(element){
    element.addClass('shake');
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.removeClass('shake');
    },2100);
};
```

Then the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.shake {
display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear
}
```

Here's an example:

```
if (!phone.length > 0) {
    shakeElement($signupPhoneInput);
    showAlert('error','Please enter your phone number.');
    $signupPhoneInput.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These events are firing simultaneously. You might want to setTimeout() them to fire within 500ms or something like that. You more than likely can use a callback to fire them in an order like so:

```
$('.notification').hide(250, function(){
    $('.notification').slideDown(250);
    $('.form-container').effect('shake');
});
```

This is using chaining and a callback to trigger the events in a more controlling manor.